# Using onSelect property of materialUI autocomplete form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a search form with autocomplete suggestions that pulls data from API. I got everything to work in terms of displaying data and selection, but I would like to automatically take the user to the related page once they select one of the suggestions.

```
<Autocomplete
                id="search-input"
                freeSolo
                disableClearable
                options={playerList}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.nickname}
                style={{ width: 200}}
                **onClick={console.log("you clicked")}
                onSelect={(val)=> window.location.href = "/player-statistics/"+val.nickname+"-"+val.account_id+"-"+server}**
                onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                    setInputValue(newInputValue);
                    if (newInputValue.length >= 3) {fetchPlayers(newInputValue)}
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search Players" variant="outlined" margin="normal" />}
            />
```

I have tried with onChange and onSelect, but they are both reloading the page continuously whenever you press the search field or start typing.

The idea is to skip the need to click "search" button.

Comment: I think you want `onSubmit` not on the Autocomplete component but on the form wrapping it.

Comment: that's the thing, I don't want to use a button at all on this form.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a suggested name, `onInputChange` is triggered.
There you need to put the logic for changing the location.
Then the user does not have to click anything else.
If you do not want the page to change when the user only types a single character,
then you need to write logic for that inside `onInputChange`.

sth. like

```
   // inside onInputChange
   if(isASuggestedName(newInputValue)) {
       //...change location
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after going through the API.

onChange call has 3 parameters - function(event: object, value: T | T[], **reason: string**) => void

I basically set it up so relocation is triggered only if reason is **select-option** and it works perfectly.

Thank you everyone